# How do I reset a Google Cloud Linux VM ssh *password*?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I am attempting to connect via ssh to my Google Cloud linux VM instance. The SSH keys have transferred, but the CLI is prompting me to enter a password. I cannot recall what this is. Is there any way to reset the ssh password?

This throws the following error when I cannot input it correctly:

user@compute.7354386071665607891's password:
user@[IP]: Permission denied (publickey,password).

I've seen answers regarding how to handle this error when it just throws "Publickey", but my particular error is preventing me from logging on through any method, including Google Cloud's browser method. In addition, I have attempted to clone the boot disk to a new VM and the same thing happens.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset the password of a VM using the [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript?hl=en). From the instance details page click on Edit mode, you can see the `Custom metadata`

For key use `startup-script`   
For value use the below script

```
#! /bin/bash

echo 'username:PASSWORD' | chpasswd
```

Please reboot your machine once you configure the startup script and then you are able to login to the machine using the password 'PASSWORD'.

Comment: I did this and can log in via serial console now. Any advice on what to do next? I'm still not able to get in via "normal" ssh.

Comment: try login via SSH

Comment: still getting the same error. maybe i'm misunderstanding what the "username" should be in the startup script, since ssh is prompting me with the "[username]@compute.[bunch of numbers]" login

Comment: @AlexNewhouse username is an example in the startup script, you need to change it with yours like echo 'alex:hereisyourpassword' | chpasswd

Comment: Yeah, I used my normal google username there but I'm still getting blocked when trying to login via ssh. Seems like using that startup script will only add a user for use within the serial console, rather than helping with the ssh password?

Comment: Oh, figured it out. Thanks so much.